# Reverse the second half of array elements in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

Here, I have written a program that traverses and reverses the last part of the array elements, like if the array is `[5, 17, 11, 10, 12, 6]`, and I want output like `[5, 17, 11, 6, 12, 10]`, so I have written a program, but the output is not coming out as expected. Can you please check and modify that so that I will get the desired result?

```js
let a = [5, 17, 11, 10, 12, 6];
let n = a.length;
for (let i = 0, j = (n / 2) - 1; i < n / 4; i++, j--) {
  let temp = a[n / 2 + i];
  a[n / 2 + i] = a[j];
  a[j] = temp;

}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  console.log(a[i])
}
```

Comment: What constitutes "*half*" if `a.length % 2 != 0`?

Comment: "*the output is not coming out as expected*" What *is* the output you're observing? Can you ensure you include this as part of your [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for all the extra rigmarole you've got to loop over `Array` elements - instead, [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the original array halfway, [`reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the spliced values, then [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) them all back into `a`.

```js
let a = [5, 17, 11, 10, 12, 6];
let b = a.splice(a.length / 2).reverse();
a.push(...b);
console.log(a); // [5, 17, 11, 6, 12, 10]
```

As I mentioned in my comment - be forewarned that this will not function the way you seemingly want it to if `a.length % 2 != 0`, so you may consider using [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) on the calculation of `a.length / 2` - the acceptability of this will depend on your requirements and constraints.`

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the array in two parts and reverse the secondHalf using the `reverse` js method.

If you don't want to use the `reverse` you can follow this approach:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const half = Math.ceil(array.length / 2);

let firstHalf = array.splice(0, half);
let secondHalf = array.splice(-half);
let secondHalfReversed = [];

for (let i = secondHalf.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  secondHalfReversed.push(secondHalf[i]);
}

const finalArray = [...firstHalf, ...secondHalfReversed];

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to @esqew but a version that doesn't mutate the original array..

And his comments on none even array lengths still applies here.

```js
let a = [5, 17, 11, 10, 12, 6];
let h = a.length / 2;
let r = [
  ...a.slice(0, h),
  ...a.slice(h).reverse()
];

console.log(r); // [5, 17, 11, 6, 12, 10]
```